# JavaFX Sort textfile output

Tags: java, sorting, javafx

I'm a student and learning java at this moment. We have to make a programming project for the next school year and I started working on my project some days ago so I have enought time to finish it. I wanted to make a leaderboard for my game. When you die a little screen will pop up where you can enter your name and your name + your score will be saved in a textfile then. Now, because it's a leaderboard, I have to sort it from the highest to lowest score. I kinda (maybe) know how to sort it with only integers but this is a string with an extra name instead of an int so you know who scored that score. Does anyone know how to do this?

Textfile looks like this:

```
Max Mustermann - 10000
Max Muster - 40000
John Smith - 80000
Iam Uncreative - 20000
```

My current code to read the file: (I'm working with JavaFX btw)

```
try {
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( file ) );

   String x;
   while ( ( x = br.readLine() ) != null ) {
      String s = tLB.getText();
      tLB.setText( s + "\n" + x );
   }
} catch(Exception E) {
   System.out.println( "cant read leaderboard" );
}
```

I don't have a code to save to the file yet because I'm not that far with my project. Just wanna sort some manually saved strings from the textfile

I'll appreciate any kind of help :)
And sorry for my bad grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a class to hold each of the leaders from the leaderboard like below:

```
    static class LeaderBoardEntry implements Comparable {
    String name;
    int score;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        return ((LeaderBoardEntry) o).score - this.score;
    }
}
```

Here implementing the Comparable interface allows us to compare leaders to get a natural ordering based on their score.

Next, I would modify your code like below, so that I get the sorted leaderboard to display,

```
try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        List<LeaderBoardEntry> leaders = new ArrayList<>();

        String x;
        while ((x = br.readLine()) != null) {
            LeaderBoardEntry leaderBoardEntry = new LeaderBoardEntry();
            String[] splits = x.split(" - ");
            leaderBoardEntry.setName(splits[0]);
            leaderBoardEntry.setScore(Integer.parseInt(splits[1]));
            leaders.add(leaderBoardEntry);
        }


        Collections.sort(leaders);

        StringBuilder leaderBoardStr = new StringBuilder();

        for (LeaderBoardEntry leaderBoardEntry : leaders) {
            leaderBoardStr.append(leaderBoardEntry.getName())
                    .append(" - ")
                    .append(leaderBoardEntry.getScore())
                    .append("\n");
        }

        String s = tLB.getText();
        tLB.setText( s + "\n" + leaderBoardStr.toString());

    } catch (Exception E) {
        System.out.println("cant read leaderboard");
    }
```

Comment: It worked, thank you a lot! :) I though it would be more complicated :D

Comment: Be wary of unexpected username input (e.g. Julia Louis - Dreyfus).

Answer (score 0):

As with all moderately complex CS problems, you'll want to break this down into separate problems:

1. Read lines from file.
2. Sort lines.
3. Aggregate sorted lines into a string.

Something like the below would work:

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\d+$");
public static void main(String[] pArgs) throws IOException {
  try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("file.txt"))) {
    System.out.println(
      stream.sorted(
        Comparator.comparing(
          pLine -> {
            final Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(pLine);
            matcher.find();
            return Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(0));
          }
        )
      ).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: already implemented the one above since its just a school project but when I'll create a bigger project once then I'll try out yours for sure. Thanks for your help! :)